# Use Sass @forward with variable

Tags: sass

How can I use previous declared variables inside sass @forward with configuration?

Example

```
// _library.scss
$black: #000 !default;
$white: #FFF !default;
$heading-color: $black !default;
```

```
// _opinionated.scss
@forward 'library' with (
  $heading-color: $white !default,
);
```

is that even possible?

Comment: Here is a video that might help you in using forward and use. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0&list=PLlwbAGSVMKHrkw8qJHSXePgvYRwy9i-8Q&index=42&t=6s